# trying to get two floats out of a string python

Tags: python

so I have txt file which has the following 2 values 0.8812395E-5.1.000E+01 but when printing on python it says that the list's two components are [0.8812395E-5.1.000E+01, ''] basically instead of considering the two values separately it takes the two as one,  I need to extract the two numbers.

```
pressure = open('pressure.txt')
pressure = pressure.read()
line = pressure.split('\n')
print(len(line))
print(line)
```

and the result

```
2
['.8812395E-15.1000000E+01', '']
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: " instead of considering the two values separately" -  the problem is that your values are separated by nothing. If you can, you should try to obtain better structured data first.

Comment: Try splitting it by `'-'` as they are not in two lines but in one separated by a dash, if I understand your notation correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the format of the text file? It would be easier to split them using a unique character to separate them, such as a comma. Right now they are separated with a decimal which is used also in the scientific notation.

Comment: @big_bad_bison The values are not separated by a dot, it's part of the second value: `.1000E+01'

Comment: Your current data is ambiguous. It could be interpreted as `.8812395E-15` and `.1000000E+01`, or as `.8812395E-1` and `5.1000000E+01`. As others have said, you need to separate the values in some way.

Comment: Where does the second value begins?

Comment: the values are separated by the dot '.' so they are .8812395E-15 and .1000000E+01

Comment: @ThierryLathuille If the first value has a leading zero, I would assume the second would also have a leading zero then? In which case it has to be a period separating them I think? Regardless, the formatting needs to be changed.

Answer (score -1):

Are the numbers on the same line? You could use

```
line.replace('.','#0.').split('#',2)
```

You then just need to drop the first blank value.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comments, if you can you should change the delimiter between values if you can. Since the decimal is used in the scientific notation, it is difficult to effectively split the string. If you can use a comma instead, it becomes much easier.

If you can't modify the formatting, this code will split the string on all decimals, then piece the values back together.

```
pressure = '0.8812395E-5.1.000E+01'
seg = pressure.split('.')
for i in range(0, len(seg), 2):
    f = float('.'.join(seg[i:i + 2]))
    print(f)
```

Output:

```
8.812395e-06
10.0
```